# Airflow Taskflows: Chaining tasks with return values

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

How do I declare dependencies between tasks using Airflow's new Taskflow API?

Let's consider the following example:

```py
@dag(
    dag_id="chaining_tests",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 11, 1),
    schedule=None
)
def chaining_tests(): 
    
    @task
    def validate_parameters(params=None):
        ## validate params, raise Airflow Exceptions otherwise
        pass
    
    @task
    def load_candidates(params=None) -> list[int]:
        return [1,2,3,4]
    
    @task
    def transform_candidate(candidate: int, params=None) -> str:
        return candidate+1
    
    
    # declaring dependencies here
    validate_parameters()
    candidates = load_candidates()
    transform_candidates = transform_candidate.expand(candidate=candidates)
    # cont'ed

chaining_tests()
```

The dependency graph in the Airflow Webui looks like this:
[image: dependency graph]

I want the task "load candidates" to be executed after "validate parameters"

**What I have tried so far**

*Option 1: pass parameter*

```py
 # declaring dependencies here
 valid = validate_parameters()
 candidates = load_candidates(valid)
```

This obviously works, but it smells. We pass a parameter to downstreams tasks without any intention to use it.

*Option 2: use the shift operators*

The naive approach, mixing Airflow 1.x and Airflow 2.x syntax.

```py
# declaring dependencies here
validate_parameters() >> candidates = load_candidates()
```

Of course not.

```py
# declaring dependencies here
validate_parameters()
candidates = load_candidates()
    
validate_parameters >> load_candidates
```

Not allowed, error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: '_TaskDecorator' and '_TaskDecorator'`

```py
candidates = load_candidates() << validate_parameters()
results = transform_candidate.expand(candidate=candidates)
```

Exception, error: `airflow.exceptions.XComForMappingNotPushed: did not push XCom for task mapping`

*Option 3: assign to XCom Magic*

Found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75587469/2618629), but how it works remains unclear.

```py
result1 = validate_parameters()  # this returns nothing
result2 = load_candidates()
result3 = transform_candidate.expand(candidate=result2)
result1 >> result2 >> result3
```

This works, but now we are actually not defining the dependencies between tasks, but Airflow return values? Still feels like a hack. And it's still the old syntax, and the [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/tutorial_taskflow_api.html) promises

> In contrast, with the TaskFlow API in Airflow 2.0, the invocation itself automatically generates the dependencies

*Option 4: the "pythonic" way*

```py
if validate_parameters(): 
   candidates = load_candidates() 
   results = transform_candidate.expand(candidate=candidates)
```

Here we should have clear dependencies, the task "load_candidates" is clearly dependent on "validate_parameters". Airflow doesn't agree, we are back to the beginning in our graph.

**The question**
Is there any way to declare dependencies on methods without return values using only the new Airflow 2.x Taskflow syntax?

If not, what is the best practice here? (with focus on readability for programmers without deep Airflow knowledge).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with mixing traditional (>>) dependencies with Taskflow, imho this is the clearest way of expressing the intent:

```
transform_candidate.expand(candidate=(validate_parameters() >> load_candidates()))
```

If you want, nothing prevents you from declaring `validate_parameters` an argument of load_candidates, even though in reality it doesn't expect any:

```
transform_candidate.expand(candidate=(load_candidates(validate_parameters())))
```

Finally most verbose:

```
candidates = load_candidates()
validate_parameters() >> candidates
transform_candidate.expand(candidate=candidates)
```

In the end it's all matter of taste, all of above are equivalent and result in:

[image]